# bootstrap collapse not show all demo

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a php file in which I use bootstrap collapse in the following way:

```
   <div class="text-center" id="bott">
   <p>
   <button class="bottone-isbn btn-lg btn-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="demo1">
    ISBN
  </button>
  <button class="bottone-key btn-lg btn-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="demo2">
    Parola chiave (titolo, autore)
  </button>
  <button class="bottone-manuale btn-lg btn-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="demo3">
    Manualmente
  </button>
</p>
</div>
```

the code of the three demo is very long, I'll show you how the demo1 is. The second is very similar while in the third I inserted a form.

```
<div class="collapse" id="demo1">
    <br>
    <br>
   <div class="card card-body">
      <ul>
         <h1><li>ISBN: </li></h1> 
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="container" id="cerca">
               <div class="search-container"> 

                  <form action="aggiungiLibro.php" method="GET" name="search-form">
                     <input id="search-input" size="40" type="text" placeholder="    Inserisci ISBN..." name="isbn">
                     <button name="invio" id="search-button" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-check" style="color:white;"></i></button>
                  </form>

               </div>
            </div>
         <h1 class="text-center">Libri trovati:</h1>
            <br>
            <?php
                  if (isset($_GET["invio"])) {
                     $isbn=$_GET["isbn"];
                     $query="SELECT * FROM libri_DB WHERE libri_DB.isbn = '$isbn'";

                  }
                  $result=mysqli_query($db, $query);
                  $result_check=mysqli_num_rows($result);
                  if ($result_check > 0) {
                        for ($i=1; $i <= $result_check; $i++) {
                           $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                           $libro=$row["nome"];

                           //layout ricerca
                           $risultato='
                           <div class="container"> <!--container singolo libro -->

                              <!-- riga 1 -->
                              <div class="row mb-5 mb-lg-0 mt-5" id="libro">

                                 <!-- tabella di una sola riga e due colonne -->
                                 <div class="column"> <!-- colonna con immagine -->
                                    <img class="card-img" src="img/libri/'.$row["immagine_libro"].'" alt=""/>
                                 </div>

                                 <div class="column"> <!-- colonna con info --> 
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                       <h2 class="card-title text-white ml-4 mt-3 mb-3">'.$row["nome"].'</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body" id="descrizione"> <!-- lista caratteristiche -->
                                       <ul id="dati-libro">
                                          <li class="card-text text-white"><u>Autore:</u> '.$row["autore"].'</li>
                                          <li class="card-text text-white"><u>Anno pubblicazione:</u> '.$row["data_pubblicazione"].'</li>
                                          <li class="card-text text-white"><u>Casa editrice:</u> '.$row["editore"].'</li>
                                          <li class="card-text text-white"><u>Numero di pagine:</u> '.$row["pagine"].'</li>
                                          <li class="card-text text-white"><u>ISBN:</u> '.$row["isbn"].'</li>
                                       </ul>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>';
                           print $risultato;
                        }
                     }
             ?>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that most of the time it only shows me the first demo I defined and it works, but doesn't show me the others. Sometimes it works for all demo and sometimes it works only the first. Why?
in the file head I have included the following links:

```
<head>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- my CSS -->
<link href="css/aggiungiLibro.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/aggiungiLibro.js"></script>

<!--funzione per chiudere collapse button attuale quando ne apro uno diverso -->
<script>
  $(document).on('click','#bott',function(){
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
  }) 
</script>
</head>
```

The last function closes all other demos when I open one. If I remove the function, bootstrap doesn't close the demos automatically.

EDIT: I noticed that if I delete the php code inside the three demos, everything works fine. If instead I insert the php code then I have the problem. But I need the php code. How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me point out a few things

1. Bootstrap requires `popper` to function. You need to include popper.min.js before you include bootstrap.min.js
2. You have an onclick event listener on the parent div tag (`#bott`). This is not required. If you have the right markup (as per bootstrap instructions) event listeners for collapse will be handled automatically. Read more in the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/).
3. If you define `aria` attributes you should use correct data. The `aria-controls` attribute will have the actual element ids that the buttons are controlling, ie. `demo1`, `demo2` and `demo3`. The script will work without these too but it is recommended to use correct markup. Read about aria attributes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA)

The codes will look like this

```html
<head>
    <!-- Using the recommended CDN links from bootstrap -> check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/ -->

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
          crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>


<div class="text-center"
     id="bott">
    <p>
        <button class="bottone-isbn btn-lg btn-info"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#demo1"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-controls="demo1">
            ISBN
        </button>
        <button class="bottone-key btn-lg btn-info"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#demo2"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-controls="demo2">
            Parola chiave (titolo, autore)
        </button>
        <button class="bottone-manuale btn-lg btn-info"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#demo3"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-controls="demo3">
            Manualmente
        </button>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="collapse"
     id="demo1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="card card-body">
        <ul>
            <h1>
                <li>ISBN:</li>
            </h1>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="container"
                 id="cerca">
                <div class="search-container">
                    Demo 1
                    <form action="aggiungiLibro.php"
                          method="GET"
                          name="search-form">
                        <input id="search-input"
                               size="40"
                               type="text"
                               placeholder="    Inserisci ISBN..."
                               name="isbn">
                        <button name="invio"
                                id="search-button"
                                type="submit">
                            <i class="fas fa-check" style="color:white;"></i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="collapse"
     id="demo2">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="card card-body">
        Demo 2
    </div>
</div>

<div class="collapse"
     id="demo3">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="card card-body">
        Demo 3
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

This is the working JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/xz9bynu8/

Bonus: Do not use `<br>` tags to create space use bootstrap [utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/) like `mt-2` etc.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I tried to modify everything as you suggested but I always have the same problem and I don't understand why. The first demo I write works and the others don't work

Comment: Check the jsfiddle link, it is working. If you need more help share the entire page.

Comment: if I copy and paste the code you suggested it actually works. If I change the content of the demos to what I need it doesn't work anymore. I have to check if I'm wrong to write something

Comment: Yes, you can start by inspecting the divs in the browser dev tools to see if the visibility changes when you click on a button. Its possible you may have nested the required divs incorrectly but without looking at the codes, its just a guess.

Comment: I did several tests, maybe I understood where the problem is. Inside the demos I have a piece of php code because I need to communicate with my database. If I don't insert the php code, it opens all the demos, for example if I insert the php code in the first one, then the others won't show them to me. How can I do?

Comment: php code is unrelated to the functioning of bootstrap and js. php is executed `server side`  and js and html are `client side`. What that means is any php code will run first on the server, generate a response and send it to the browser. Once the browser has loaded the response, js will work on it. Both are mutually exclusive. Without special means php can never call a JS function (even if they are coded on the same page) and vice versa. As for your error, your php codes may be generating incorrect markup. You have not shared codes, so I cannot guess.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I modified the question by including the php code. Can you take a look? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: This is just the first demo container right? What about the other two?

Comment: As a first point your query is defined inside an if block and it is used outside the if block. If you use an if block it should include all the codes dependent on that if. Also did you check for [`mysqli_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). You should also enable error_reporting with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the file

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that the query is defined in the if block and used outside the block. I modified putting everything in the if block and it works !!
Thank you very much for helping. You were very kind and very helpful. Of course I had made the same mistake in the other demos as well. Now everything is working as it should! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should be using the ids of the collapsibles you want to control on your buttons aria-controls attribute,

so `aria-controls="collapseExample1"` should be `aria-controls="demo1"` and so on.

Also I don't understand why you are using this:

```
<script>
  $(document).on('click','#bott',function(){
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
  }) 
</script>
```

Because you are binding to close the collapse divs when you click on your `#boot` div which contains all your buttons. I don't know what you try to achieve with this code as it is not 100% clear from your question but I think that you need to remove this from your code.

Comment: I am using this function because when I clicked on a button it opened the corresponding demo, and when I clicked on another button it opened the demo but it did not close the previous one. However I changed aria-control and removed the function but it doesn't work anyway